# Ferry connection between Crimea (Ukraine) and Georgia?

Tags: ferries, georgia-country, black-sea, ukraine

Is there any reliable ferry connection between Crimea on Ukraine and Georgia? Does anyone have any information on that?

Comment: Wow I was positive somebody asked this weeks ago!

Comment: do we have to update titles due to geopolitical events?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do such trip by "[UkrFerry](http://www.ukrferry.com/eng/shipping/schedule-ports.php)" company:

> From Kerch to Poti every Tuesday, at next day you are at Poti. Operations service phone: +38 (0482) 34-76-63.

According to [official forum](http://www.ukrferry.com/forum/topic/21-poti-kerch/), schedule is set at the start of each month, so you should call there before you came in Kerch. Also there is a line Batumi - Ilyichevsk, which is more popular line (ferry goes each 2-3 days), and you have more chances to use it than Poti - Kerch.

Comment: Do you know how reliable this connection is? I mean if it really every Tuesday or you can be stalled in Kerch?

Comment: @pixel Updated the answer.

Answer (score 10):

A Dutch friend of mine just took this ferry in the Georgia→Ukraine direction so I asked him for some details:

- **Company name**: UkrFerry
- **Ship name**: Greifswald
- **Quoted boarding time in Batumi**: 10pm
- **Actual departure time from Batumi**: ~ 8am
- **Quoted duration of trip**: 60 hours
- **Actual duration of trip**: ~ 55 hours
- **Price**: USD $170 for a bed in a 2-bed cabin

There were also 4-bed cabins that were only a few dollars cheaper.

[image: UkrFerry "Greifswald" at Batumi]

Apparently nobody at the office speaks any English and even when taking a Georgian friend to help a lot of details including which night the ferry departed were very unclear - so be prepared! For instance he was told to be at the ferry at 10pm but it didn't actually leave until about 8am!

There are three good quality meals per day included in the price but nobody speaks English. All announcements etc are in Russian only.

Also there is nothing at all to do on the ferry. Just one TV which is in Russian, and it's hard to go above deck.

---

Thanks very much to Rowan for letting me grill him.

Comment: Interesting 2008 write-up about these ferries: [The Ukraine-Georgia Black Sea ferry is no package tour](http://www.monstersandcritics.com/lifestyle/travel/features/article_1411733.php/The_Ukraine-Georgia_Black_Sea_ferry_is_no_package_tour)