# Does the Ukraine-Georgia ferry go via Russia and if so must I have a Russian visa even if I don't disembark?

Tags: visas, russia, ferries, georgia-country, ukraine

Previously we had a question about [ferries between Ukraine and the Republic of Georgia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/921/ferry-connection-between-crimea-ukraine-and-georgia). The answer was that the company [UkrFerry](http://www.ukrferry.com/eng/shipping/schedule-ports.php) has such a route but I'm unsure of the details and the site seems to be mostly in Russian.

What I'm wondering is if the ferry goes via Russia and if so is it possible to travel say from Kerch to Poti without the need to obtain a Russian visa? (Impossible for me anyway since I would have to apply in Australia and I'm already in Europe).

Comment: Just a comment to the Russian Visa. You don't have to apply in your home country all the time. Practically you can apply in every Russian embassy of the world, but it really depends on the person at the counter if your visa is granted.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: Are you sure about this? Everything I've heard says it's not possible, though perhaps that depends on the country of the applicant. We do have [a question on applying for one from Tbilisi, Georgia](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/295/can-i-apply-for-a-russian-visa-from-the-republic-of-georgia) you might want to comment on or I could ask a new question.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, since I did the same this summer. But as I said, the official rule is you are not allowed to do that. But sometimes the embassy employees are friendly and allow it.

Comment: What passport do you travel under? And at which embassy did you apply?

Comment: I have a passport from Liechtenstein. And I once applied in Germany and once in Switzerland.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. As I know, you definitely don't need the Russian visa if you are not going to leave the ship during stay in port. So you need to worry about it.
2. Russian embassies can help you to obtain Russian visa due your unusual situation, so you can try it all the time - we are all the people, and you always can try to communicate with embassy. Also you should note what **2011 year is a start year for the 2011-2018 tourism campaign**, and you have great chance to solve your problem.
3. The nearest shipment from Kerch to the Poti will be tomorrow, so you shouldn't be afraid for this ship is not available. Also I'd like to note that **this route is direct and has no stops in Russia.**

Comment: Worth to note that now (2014) the ferry ***does*** require a Russian visa, as Kerch is in now de facto Russia.