# Dual citizen applying for Russian visa with only other country's passport

Tags: visas, passports, regulations, russia, dual-nationality

My friend has British and Australian citizenship. He is currently on a visit to Australia with only his British passport. (His expired Australian passport is in London and needs to be renewed anyway.)

Now Russia has a policy that you can only apply for a Russian visa from a country where you are a resident.

But if you are a resident of the country in which you apply but only in possession of the passport of your other country, will they still issue you a visa?

Basically, do we know the nitty-gritty of this particular rule Russia has?

Comment: Is this a new rule? I've heard of British people who successfully applied for a Russian visa in Beijing. This was in 2012 though.

Comment: Not a new rule at all - was like that when I applied in 2008 and 2011.  You could apply in the country where you were citizen OR where you were resident - so as a Kiwi living in London, I could apply there.

Comment: Ok, I must've misunderstood something then from the British guys I met. They were just travelling and were residents of the UK but (they told me) that during their travels they got a Russian visa in Beijing to enter Russia and go to Ukraine.

Comment: I was thinking about this.  I mean, to 'prove' residency in the UK, I'm not sure they even looked at my visa - they wanted my address of residence - but there's nothing stopping you putting down a hostel address or similar? I'd give it a go, or just go in and ask them if possible - they may have suggestions.

Comment: For a previous question about this rule, see **[How can I maximize my chances of obtaining a Russian visa outside my home country?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/how-can-i-maximize-my-chances-of-obtaining-a-russian-visa-outside-my-home-countr?rq=1)**

Answer (score 6):

The nitty-gritty depends on the consular worker you encounter but then there is a different problem.

If you look at the application that needs to be submitted to the Consulate for a VISA there are 2 different forms:

- [Everyone except citizens of US, Great Britain, Canada, and Georgia](http://www.kdmid.ru/content/cnslfunk_doc/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8B/LAT_form_A4.pdf)
- [Citizens of US, Great Britain, Canada, and Georgia](http://www.kdmid.ru/content/cnslfunk_doc/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8B/LAT_USA_%D0%904.pdf)

You can take a look at [consular service page](http://www.kdmid.ru/cons.aspx?lst=cnslfunk&it=/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%20-%20%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B5.aspx).  Given the length of the form he will be required to submit with his British Passport I would suggest that he renew his Australian passport and apply for Russian visa with it.

Sorry the portal is in Russian.